# Python saving dictionarys in files. Problem with "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, dictionary, text-files

I´m doing a phonebook thing for a project using the dictionarys.
Everything has been going fine untill this problematic part where I save the newly added keys and values.
I wonder where im doing wrong?

```
Katalog={"Edd":["4858"],
         "Zaa":["4202"],
          }

def save(Katalog):
    badChars = [",""[","]","'"]
    savelist=[]
    filname=input()
    f=open(filname,"w")
    for namn in Katalog:
        savelist.append(namn)
        savelist.append(":")

        for x in Katalog[namn]:
            savelist.append(Katalog[namn][x])
            savelist.append(":")
    savelist.append("\n")

    saveList = ''.join(i for i in saveList if not i in badChars)
    f.write(savelist)
    f.close()
```

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Can you show us a [Minimal, Verifiable, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? From your code, we have no idea what `Katalog` is and what it contains, for example.

Comment: looks like `x` or `namn` are string instead of int and he is getting this error because there is iteration over as `for x in Katalog[namn]`

Comment: what is `Katalog`? please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: line which says : savelist.append(Katalog[namn][x])

Comment: Katalog is the dictionary

Comment: Sorry for not doing the mcve, first question on stackoverflow

Comment: @SanfordBassett both are strings, but `int(namn)` will raise a ValueError, since "Edd" and "Zaa" are not convertible to integers and using `int(x)` will result in a `IndexError` since the list `["4858"]` has less than 4859 items and the list `["4202"]` has less than 4203 items. also that wouldn't do what OP wants, even if it was working with the given data

Comment: @Aemyl Sorry, I posted that before I read that Katalog was a dictionary, not a 2d list. For some reason, I didn't think to delete the comment after I realized it was irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Katalog: Dict[str, List[str]]

for namn in Katalog:
```

`namn` is a key for `Katalog`

```
    for x in Katalog[namn]:
```

`x` is a string contained in `Katalog[namn]`

```
        savelist.append(Katalog[namn][x])
```

`Katalog[namn]` is the list which contains `x`, but using `x` as an index for it won't work. you could just change this line to `savelist.append(x)`

```
        savelist.append(":")
```

swap that line with the previous one, such that the separator is *between* key and value.

Instead of writing an own function, you could also use the `json` module from the standard library:

```
import json

def save(Katalog):

    with open(input(), "w") as f:
        josn.dump(Katalog, f)
```